# Elasticsearch-py unrecognized 'analyzer' parameter in search()

Tags: python, elasticsearch-plugin, query-analyzer

The API Document says that `search(*args, **kwargs)` has a parameter called `analyzer`. But the following code raises an exception:

> RequestError:TransportError(400, 'illegal_argument_exception', 'request [/test-index/content-field/_search] contains unrecognized parameter: [analyzer]')

```py
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
from elasticsearch.client import IndicesClient
es = Elasticsearch()
res = es.search(index="test-index", doc_type='content-field',
                body={"query": {"match": {"text": "微观文明"}}},
                analyzer="ik_smart", size=3)
```

The following code, however, returns a correct answer.

```py
i=IndicesClient(es)
res=i.analyze(index="test-index",body="我你大家",analyzer="ik_smart")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> That parameter is only used (and accepted) when using the q parameter to search via a query string. In your case you need to specify the analyzer for the match query in the body[.]

Found the answer in this github issue: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-py/issues/495